# MS Access turn off shortcut menu on subform

Tags: ms-access, subforms

I have a MS Access form that has a subform. the subform is in datasheet view and is sorted and sorted by the date column. I have a button that does a comparison checks using the first row in the subform before performing an update, and it works fine. The problem is whenever a user right click in the subform and resort the data it causes problems. 
Is there a way I can prevent users from sorting the subform?
also, if I should turn this off will the data still be sorted by the date field?

Answer (score 2):

The form should have a property `Shortcut Menu` that controls the ability to right-click when the form is in browse mode. Set that property to false to disable right-click (and sorting etc). The data should still get sorted as that is controlled by the `Order By` and `Order By On Load` properties.

Comment: your suggestion works for the most part. however the user can still access those dropdown filter buttons on the subform and short the data in the subform/datasheet. how can i hide those. I wish i could post a picture of the form so you could see what exactly I'm referring to.

Comment: @Kefash If you open the specific subform in desgn view you should be able to change the setting for `Shortcut Menu` in the same way as for the main form. At least that seem to work for me.